# C# Ftp Error - Null reference

Tags: c#, ftp

I have this code which works perfect when there is a file on FTP site , but when there is no file on FTP site it fails.
The error II get is in *foreach (string file in files)* and it says there is null reference .

How can I fix this so that if there is no file on FTP site this code will work.

Thanks in advance.

my error message
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

code

public void Main()
            {

```
            String[] files = GetFileList();
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                Download(file);
            }
        }

        public string[] GetFileList()
        {
            string[] downloadFiles;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            WebResponse response = null;
            StreamReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                //FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
                WebRequest reqFTP;
                reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + Dts.Variables["strHost"].Value+"/"));
                //reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                String FTPUser = (String)Dts.Variables["strUserName"].Value;
                String FTPPwd = (String)Dts.Variables["strPassword"].Value;
                reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FTPUser, FTPPwd);
                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                reqFTP.Proxy = null;

                //reqFTP.KeepAlive = true;
                //reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
                response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
                reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    result.Append(line);
                    result.Append("\n");
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                }
                // to remove the trailing '\n'
                result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
                return result.ToString().Split('\n');
            }
          catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }
                if (response != null)
                {
                    response.Close();
                }                
                downloadFiles = null;
                return downloadFiles;
            }

        }

        private void Download(string file)
        {
            try
            {
                string uri = "ftp://" + Dts.Variables["strHost"].Value + "/" + file;
                Uri serverUri = new Uri(uri);
                if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
                {
                    return;
                }
                WebRequest reqFTP;
                //FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
                reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + Dts.Variables["strHost"].Value + "/" + file));
                String FTPUser = (String)Dts.Variables["strUserName"].Value;
                String FTPPwd = (String)Dts.Variables["strPassword"].Value;
                reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FTPUser, FTPPwd);
                //reqFTP.KeepAlive = true;
                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                //reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                reqFTP.Proxy = null;
                //reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(Dts.Variables["strLocalFolder"].Value + "\\" + file, FileMode.Create); int Length = 2048;
                Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
                int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
                }
                writeStream.Close();
                response.Close();
            }

            catch (WebException wEx)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(wEx.Message, "Download Error");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Download Error");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test the result of GetFilesList() for null, because you return null in case an error (in catch clause of GetFileList() you set the result - downloadFiles - to null).

```
        public void Main() 
        {               
            String[] files = GetFileList();
            if (files != null)  // add this line
            {
                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                    Download(file);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your call to GetFileList returns null and thus the foreach fails.